# COVID-19 policy (Newark Airport): Can we meet passengers in arrivals / baggage claim?

Tags: covid-19, ewr, airport-terminals

Family members of mine are flying into Newark airport (from a different state), and I would like to go meet them along with my children. Are we allowed to meet them inside the arrivals terminal / baggage claim area? I can't figure out if that's prohibited due to COVID-19 policy or if it's still allowed.

Comment: If you are willing to put the effort in, you can even meet them at the gate: buy fully reimbursable tickets, go inside, cancel the tickets…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no relevant covid-related restrictions preventing people from entering the landside areas of Newark Airport, but do note that [you are required](https://www.tsa.gov/news/press/releases/2021/08/20/tsa-extends-face-mask-requirement-through-march-18-2022) to wear a face covering at all times while inside the terminal.